# Matrix columns inside a dataset converted into indepentent variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

The dataframe `gasoline` from the `pls` package consists of two variables: `octane` and a 60x401 matrix. How can I modify `gasoline` so that each of the columns of the matrix becomes an independent variable, i.e. the output of `str(gasoline)` would be 60 observations and 402 variables?

Comment: I did not get  what you want, can you explain more ?

Comment: If, for example, I try gasoline[,3], it will not work because all the columns of the matrix belong to gasoline[,2] (first column is octane).If i try gasoline[,2] then all the columns of the matrix are shown. I would like to transform gasoline so that for example gasoline[,2] shows the first column of the matrix only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cbind` :

```
mat <- cbind(gasoline$NIR, gasoline$octane)
dim(mat)
#[1]  60 402
```